# How to terminate long poll Ajax request at page leaving

Tags: ajax, comet, server-push

I have long poll Ajax request. Browser, at least but not last IE doesn't terminate the request at page leaving, so request remains open and active even if a user visits some other site. Say more, a browser can successfully process responses from this connection, although their result go nowhere. General recommendations as call htmlxml connection abort or stop for a window obviously do not work. 
So my implementation is adding extra Ajax call on unload to notify server connection holder that page is on leave, so it can send some dummy response and a browser will return the connection to pool of available after. This approach works but looks for me over engineered. Unfortunately I can observe a similar problem with some other programs, like GMAIL, it also does long poll and as result after some reloading it stops working. So if somebody found some good approach to address the problem without switching to short poll or assign connection timeout, then share your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There's an `abort()` method on IE's XHR which will manually disconnect it.

It's a bit hacky, but you could try something like:

```
<body onbeforeunload="AbortMyAjax()">
```

and use that method to abort any active long-polls.

For reference, here's a bit of code from a project of mine:

```
$this.lp = null;
function _LongPoll() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $this.lp = $.getJSON(m_PollUrl, _LongPollCallback);
}
```

And in the body beforeunload:

```
if(!!QueueManager.lp && !!QueueManager.lp.abort) QueueManager.lp.abort('PAGE_CLOSED');
```